# clojure.xml unable to find method on SAXparser

Tags: clojure

I am using clojure 1.3.0, and clojure.xml, however, trying to parse XML produces:

IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: parse for class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:79)

(this is java 1.6) - a version mismatch between sax parsers and clojure 1.3?

EDIT: I also tried Clojure 1.4, same problem. Must be a JDK issue?

Comment: Can you post the code that produces that exception?

Comment: I think I am misreading: http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.xml-api.html - it can only read from files/uris, NOT from strings/streams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was my misunderstanding of clojure.xml - when you pass it a string, it is looking for a URI of where to load the XML content. If you have XML as a string already, convert it to a stream and pass it to clojure.xml, something like:

```
(let [stream (java.io.ByteArrayInputStream. (.getBytes (.trim xml)))]
```